# fail to make xAxis on Highstock chart to go before

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a [jsFiddle here to](http://jsfiddle.net/tinybyte/Y52LE/) show my problem,

I want my chart to start on xAxis two month before than it has data on it,

how can I show from two month before?

```
   'xAxis': {
        'min': Date.UTC(2013, 4, 24, 16, 44, 10),
        'startOnTick' : false,
        'startOfWeek': 6,
        'dateTimeLabelFormats': {
            'week': '%a,<br/>%e. %b'
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start the data from the date you want to show in chart.

if there is no data give the y value as null

in your case you want the min for xAxis to be Date.UTC(2012, 1, 24, 16, 44, 10)

so start data from

`data: [
    [Date.UTC(2012, 1, 24, 16, 44, 10), null],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 24, 16, 44, 10), 336000.],
    [Date.UTC(2013, 6, 27, 13, 57, 36), 393500.]
]`

this will make the xAxis plot from the day you want.

I've updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y52LE/3/)

Comment: in your fiddle I don't see xAxis starting from 2012!? but I agree that it has a gone little further back

Comment: You need also set `xAxis.ordinal: false`, otherwise it won't display more space with just one point. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Y52LE/4/ OR add more null-points to make more space on the left edge.